# Errors when using maven plugin for Weblogic deployment

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, weblogic11g, weblogic-maven-plugin

I have been trying to deploy application to Weblogic 10.3.6 using maven

I  have created weblogic plugin for maven as mentioned in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm) article.

I have added the following to pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <goalPrefix>weblogic</goalPrefix>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin> 
  <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>10.3.6.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <adminurl>t3://localdomain:7001</adminurl>
    <user>weblogic</user>
    <password>password</password>
    <name>wldemo</name>
    <remote>true</remote>
    <upload>true</upload>
    <targets>AdminServer</targets>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>target/EmployeesApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
  </plugins>  
</build>
```

When I did mvn  com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:deploy I am getting the following errors, how can I resolve these errors?

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:10.3.6.
0:deploy (default-cli) on project EmployeesApp: The parameters 'source' for goal
 com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:10.3.6.0:deploy are missing or invali
d
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the *source* parameter in the execution configuration, so in order to make it taken into account you should invoke this particular execution. It can be done using the phase key you specified, so e.g.:

```
mvn integration-test
```

Maven will go through the whole lifecycle and on the *pre-integration-test* test phase (which precedes the *integration-test* one) it will run the execution of weblogic-maven-plugin you configured.